# TypeError: products.map is not a function. Most likely Problems are in redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, mern

How to solve this issue? I've attached all relevant code snippets here. When I'm trying to render products on the home screen, I'm getting this error, when I open this project it shows loading for a few seconds and then shows this error. What to do for fixing this error?

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions.js'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products} = productList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts())
  }, [dispatch])
    return (
        <>
            <h1>All Products</h1>
            {loading ? (
                <Loader />
            ) : error ? (
                <Message variant='danger'>{error}</ Message>
            ) : (
                <Row>
                {products.map((product) => (
                    <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3} key={product._id}>
                        <Product product={product} />
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
            )}    
        </>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

And here is the productAction page of redux

```
import {PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, 
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL} from '../constants/productConstants'
import axios from 'axios'

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })

        const {data} = await axios.get('/api/products')

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
            payload:
                error.response && error.response.data.message
                    ? error.response.data.message
                    : error.message
        })

    }
}

export const listProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST })
  
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
  
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      })
    }
  }
```

productReducers page:

```
import {PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL} from '../constants/productConstants'

export const productListReducer = (state = { products: []}, action ) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, products: []}
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, products: action.payload}
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const productDetailsReducer = (
    state = { product: { reviews: [] } },
    action
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true, ...state }
      case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, product: action.payload }
      case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you check the response data? Is it array ?

Comment: Can you show the reducer part?

Comment: @AbinThaha it's added now.

Comment: @AzizulTareq  debug at the point of state, and check what you are receiving in state, I guess, the `productList` key is the issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding `action.payload.products` to productReducers page.
Fixed code is here:

```
export const productListReducer = (state = { products: []}, action ) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true, products: []}
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, products: action.payload.products}
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First see if your API is working correctly.
2. If it is working correctly and even then you are having this error then problem lies in way you are updating your redux store.
   Here products is element from productList. You are changing property of an object but the object itself seems to not change from React viewpoint.

Check your reducer logic and if you are updating store value do it like this

```
initialState = { loading, error, products: [] }
......
......
  return {
     ...state,
     products: [...fetched products]
  }
```

this 3 dots (...) ensure that you create a new object. On redux you have to always create a new object, not just update the state.

3. While using variables, always first verify that variable and its property that you want to use exist. In your case you directly use products.map, and this break the frontend. First check if products is really a list or not then use products.map. This way your frontend will not break even if products value is undefined.